# Bitwise Logic on a Microcontroller

Tags: assembly, avr

Given the short example below, is there any way to reduce the amount of registers used in the code between [x1] and [x2]?

I read Input from PINA and generate output for PORTB according to some logic table. 
This is the most straightforward way to do this for me, but it seems kind of roundabout. Is there a more elegant way that I am not aware of?

```
loop:
;Set Masks for Inputpins [x1]
ldi r17, 0b00000010
ldi r18, 0b00000100
;Read Input from PINA
in r16, PINA
;Apply Masks and normalize
and r17, r16
lsl r17
and r18, r16
lsl r18
lsl r18
;Start with actual bitwise operations e.g [x2]
mov r16, r17
xor r16, r18
and r16, r17
...
...
out PORTB, r16
rjmp loop
```

Note that I am not as much interested in perfomance (space, speed) as in reducing the amount of mask and shift operations which introduce (sloppy / nasty) errors easily on a bigger scale.

Also Note that I am not sure if [Codereview.Stackechange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the more appropiate place for this question.

Comment: if you care about error then why not use a compiler?

Comment: You mean writing C Code and using gcc -S ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but after `Apply Masks and normalize` it looks like `r17` will either contain 0 or 4, and `r18` will either contain 0 or 16. So at `xor r16, r18` you've got two sets of bits with no 1s in common, which will make the `xor` behave as an `or`, and the `and` on the next line appears to be pointless.

Comment: @Michael : Perfectly observed, as this part doesn't really do anything for my example I wanted to leave it blank. It's just suggesting that there WILL be operations on these registers.

Comment: Don't think there's a way to cut down on the number of registers, especially if you need the pristine input in r16. Also, if you're concerned about mask and shift operations, you're in for some trouble. Masking and shifting are one of the foundations of low-level programming like this.

Comment: @TriskalJM : You can make that an answer also as I asked for any way to do reduce operations - if there is none it counts too ;-)
I already feared it would be that way, but sometimes I just kind of overlook simple alternatives that can save a lot. 
If this naive approach is what it takes I am happy to use it, but I would be pretty frustrated if there was an easier way around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can cut down on the number of registers used in this particular case because it looks like you want to keep the contents of `r16` pristine.

If you didn't need to do that, you could use the `andi` instruction to load the bitmasks as immediate data.

Comment: The sbrs and sbrc operations are kind of usefull for more simple masking situations, just wanted to add this for future visitors.